# Managing rapidly growing "outbox" table when implementing "Transactional Outbox Pattern"

Tags: postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium, cdc

My service needs to publish messages as part of a transaction that updates the database. I am using **Postgres** and **Kafka**, and I have decided to employ the **Transactional Outbox** pattern: https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html

The main idea behind the **Transactional Outbox** pattern is to write the message as part of the same transaction that updates the application's primary data source. This ensures atomicity and consistency by guaranteeing that both the data modification and the message creation either succeed together or fail together.

Within the database transaction that involves creating, updating, and deleting business objects, the service sends messages by inserting them into an ***outbox*** table. This insertion is performed within a local ACID transaction, ensuring atomicity. The ***outbox*** table serves as a temporary message queue.

In addition, I am utilizing **Debezium** to read the **Postgres** Write-Ahead Log (WAL) for the ***outbox*** table and publish the messages to **Kafka**.

However, I am currently facing a problem with the rapid growth of my ***outbox*** table. It has become crucial for me to find a reliable solution to delete events that have already been sent.

Do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

I have come up with several possible approaches:

1. Deleting old data based on timestamps. However, this approach is not
   entirely reliable as some old data might not have been sent to
   **Kafka**.
2. Subscribing to the **Kafka** topic from the same application and
   deleting data. In this approach, we can only read data that has
   already been sent to **Kafka**. We can retrieve the message IDs from the
   topic and delete the corresponding rows from the ***outbox*** table. To
   avoid excessive delete transactions to **Postgres**, it would be
   advisable to handle messages in large batches.
3. Using the same logic as in the second approach but creating a
   separate microservice specifically for deleting data from the ***outbox***
   table. This would allow us to scale this solution independently from
   the main service.